# Combine factors via majority vote into one in R

Tags: r

I have three factor vectors with the same number of levels like this:

```
eins <- c("no", "yes", "no")
zwei <- c("no", "no", "no")
drei <- c("yes", "yes", "no")
```

Now I would need to combine them based on the majority factor level. So in this example:

```
combined
[1] "no" "yes"   "no"
```

I know how to build a foor loop and then use if statements to create a new vector, but I wanted to know if there is a faster/better way in R.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure who downvoted. This is far from obvious to do without resorting to looping over each row, which will be painfully slow on bigger data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
a <- apply(cbind(eins, zwei, drei), 1, table)
sapply(a, function(x) names(x)[which.max(x)])
#[1] "no"  "yes" "no"
```

Comment: If I run that, R creates a list and the result is: "1" "1" "2"

Comment: @Lennie I have just rerun the code in a clean RStudio session, starting with the creation of `eins`, `zwei`, `drei`, and it outputs what is in my answer. Can you post the value of `print(a)`?

Comment: I deleted .RData and .RHistory. Works like a charm now, perfect, thanks!